How to create ensemble keras model with multiple outputs
I have a multi-output keras model. In my model training I train 10 identical models and average their predictions in sequence. I would like to do all of this model training simultaneously to save time, rather than needing a loop.
Below is a minimal version of the model builder function:
def test_build_mt(input_shape):

    inputlayer = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

    shared_net = models.Sequential([layers.Dense(4, name='shared_0')], name='shared')(inputlayer)

    outputs = []
    for i in range(2):

        task_net = models.Sequential(
            [
                layers.Dense(4, name='task_hidden_0'),
                layers.Dense(1, name='task' + str(i) + '_output')
            ], 
            name='task' + str(i)
        )(shared_net)

        outputs.append(task_net)
    
    model = models.Model(inputs=inputlayer, outputs=outputs)

    return model

After consulting several posts online I have come up with the following function to build the ensemble
def test_build_ensemble(build_func, params, n_estimators=10):

    estimators = []
    for i in range(n_estimators):

        m = build_func(**params)
        estimators.append(m)

        for l in m.layers:

            l.name = 'ensemble_' + str(i) + '_' + l.name

    inputs = [m.input for m in estimators]
    outputs = [out for m in estimators for out in m.output]

    avg = layers.Average(name='ensemble_output')(outputs)

    ensemble = models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=avg)

    loss_dict = {
        'ensemble_' + str(i) + '_' 'task' + str(j): 'mean_squared_error' for i in range(n_estimators) for j in range(2)
    }

    ensemble.compile(loss=loss_dict, optimizer='nadam')

    return ensemble

When I train the model...
X = np.random.random((10,10))
y = X.sum(axis=1)
mt_y = {
    'task0': y,
    'task1': y
}


n_estimators = 2

ensemble = test_build_ensemble(test_build_mt, {'input_shape': X.shape[1:]}, n_estimators=n_estimators)

plot_model(ensemble, to_file='mt_test_ensemble.png', show_shapes=True)

ensemble.fit([X]*n_estimators,mt_y)

I get the following error:
ValueError: In the dict argument `loss`, key 'ensemble_0_task0' does not correspond to any model output. Received:
loss={'ensemble_0_task0': 'mean_squared_error', 'ensemble_0_task1': 'mean_squared_error', 'ensemble_1_task0': 'mean_squared_error', 'ensemble_1_task1': 'mean_squared_error'}

I already renamed my outputs.
Also, if I use loss_dict = {'ensemble_output': 'mean_squared_error'} I get the error: ValueError: No loss to compute. Provide a lossargument incompile().
Here is a graph of the model: 
I would greatly appreciate your help on this. However, if this is not more efficient that training models in a loop, or if there is a better way to achieve what I would like please let me know. I have checked the keras documentation on distributed computing but it seems more suitable for dividing the data or model training, rather than training several of the same models in parallel.
